# copy content of file to another file using python script

Tags: python, error-handling, openfiledialog, read-write

i have this python script that open a file dialog and select a text file than copy its content to another file.

**when i open the second file it still empty**

can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

## OPenDirectory.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Tkinter 
import tkFileDialog

''''Open txt files in the selected path '''
def OpenRead():

    Tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
    in_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(initialdir = 'C:\Users\LT GM\Downloads', filetypes=[('text files', ' TXT ')])
    readingFile = in_path.read()
    writeFile = open ('copiedFile.txt', 'w')
    writeFile.write(readingFile)
    print " we'r done!!" 
    in_path.close()
    writeFile.close()


if __name__== "__main__":
    OpenRead()
```

Comment: Try specifying the complete path to the output file, for example, `writeFile = open ('c:\\copiedFile.txt', 'w')`. Is the resulting file still empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line by line way of copying from file to file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def readWrite():
    mypath = 'D:\\'
    files = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
    for file in files:
        if file.split('.')[1] == 'txt':
            outputFileName = 'out-' + file
            with open(mypath+outputFileName, 'w') as w:
                with open(mypath+file) as f:
                    for l in f:
                        print l
                        w.write(l)

if __name__== "__main__":
    readWrite()
```

UPDATE:
updated the code above, so it reads all the txt files in a specified directory and copies them into other files. You can play with directories how you like. I also added a **"print l"** which will print the contents of the incoming file.

Comment: I updated my answer so it reads all the txt files in a specified directory and copies them

Comment: i used your code and it read and the file but it did not copy or write its content the second file

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with the way you're doing it.. works for me and works for others with similar ways..

Comment: @ admix  i solved the problem  it was the path i don't know what was the problem exactly but i changed the pass and it worked...  my second question will be about the sort of this file based on strings .....thank you

Comment: Awesome, no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `shutil.copyfile`, there is no need to open or read the file.

```
from shutil import copyfile

copyfile("source","dest")
```

So for your code:

```
 def OpenRead():
    Tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
    in_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(initialdir = 'C:\Users\LT GM\Downloads', filetypes=[('text files', ' TXT ')])
    copyfile(in_path.name, 'copiedFile.txt')
    print " we'r done!!"
if __name__== "__main__":
    OpenRead()
```

The file is also going to be copied to you pwd so if you want it save somewhere in particular you need to pass the full path.

Comment: also i tried your code but still the copiedFile.txt is empty

Comment: @Jihad3aramouni, you know what that is? Because the file you passed in is empty. This copies whatever file you open but there is not much to copy if the file is empty

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham the file  that the user select  and its saved in the  variable **in_path** its not empty the file size is 144 kb so the logic is to get the same size for the copiedFile.txt         isn't that right??     because maybe i am missing the point here

Comment: @Jihad3aramouni, whatever file you open will be copied to the destination so the only way that is not happening is if the file you pass in is empty, where are you looking for the file?

Comment: the copied file is in the same location of the source file  and i have printed the content of the file to the console and its defiantly not empty

Comment: @Jihad3aramouni, change the name of the file you are writing to and then tell me what you see

Comment: i changed to just test.txt  and still empty file

Comment: @Jihad3aramouni, I have no idea then as this code works so unless there is some very strange behaviour using windows I don't see how you get an empty file

Comment: so any way thanks for your help and your time but is very strange it could be the problem because of the path ?

Comment: You should always use raw strings for your paths  `r'C:\Users\LT GM\Downloads'`

Answer (score 0):

**`readingFile = in_path.read()`** 
reads the contents of the file and puts it in variable readingFile
suppose the contents of the file is,say, hello the value of readingFile will be hello

**`destinationFile  = readingFile, '.txt'`**
destinationFile is a tuple with values '<'contents of file'>','.txt'
instead use ***`destinationFile  = readingFile+'.txt'`***

this will work. but the end result would not be what you are expecting.the result would be a file with name as contents of the reading file with contents also the same. better specify a file name in **destinationFile** like **`destinationFile = 'destfile.txt'`**

Comment: so how to get the content of the reading file into the destination file ?

Comment: this works fine for me 'import Tkinter 
import tkFileDialog

''''Open txt files in the selected path '''
def OpenRead():

    Tkinter.Tk().withdraw()
    in_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(initialdir = 'C:\Users\LT GM\Downloads', filetypes=[('text files', ' TXT ')])
    readingFile = in_path.read()
    writeFile = open ('copiedFile.txt', 'w')
    writeFile.write(readingFile)
    print " we'r done!!" 
    in_path.close()
    writeFile.close()


if __name__== "__main__":
    OpenRead()'

Comment: what works fine for you ?? the copiedFile still empty here so what  am i missing here ??

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use os, and the shell copy command.

```
import os 
start= '~/user/file'
dest= '~/user/folder1/file'

os.system('cp %s %s' %(start,dest))
```

Comment: because i need the program to be familiar will the end user                        if i understood your question

Comment: @Jihad3aramouni what do you mean by familiar? This takes a file  and makes a copy to whatever location you wish with whatever name you wish to give it. It is all done within python, therefore the end uses doesn't have to see it, and even if they do it is pretty self explantory:  cp <location/filename>    <newlocation/newfilename>. You just need to add it to your loop.